# Nest two inner class with the main class

Tags: class-diagram, astah

I want to draw the class diagram of my Android system. I have a class which contains two inner classes in it I am facing problem to nest the both since `Astah` just allows to nest one inner class and in the case that another inner class edge is already available it is being deleted.

How can I nest two inner classes with Astah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to draw a class which has multiple inner classes. Please refer to the post below.

http://astah-users.change-vision.com/en/modules/xhnewbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=1504&post_id=4561#forumpost4561

Comment: may one inner class be nested with two other classes? I have an inner class which I have in several other classes. Can I nest this inner class with all other classes or I have to create it several times?

Comment: @Mr Asker In UML specifications, one inner class nests with only one class which means that one inner class is not able to nest with multiple classes.